# "I decided (in 2021) to go to Japan in 2023" can be simplified to "I decided to go to Japan next year"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

Imagine this year is 2022.

Last year, in 2021, I made a decision to go to Japan.
I wanted to go to Japan in 2023.

Should I say,

**Example 1**
"I decided to go to Japan next year."

or

I just say,

**Example 2**
"I decided (in 2021) to go to Japan in 2023."

Answer (score 1):

Neither is incorrect; the difference is whether the date you made the decision is important to the story.

The second is slightly awkward using brackets. You could recast it with or without commas, or move it to the front.

> I decided in 2021 to go to Japan in 2023.

> I decided, in 2021, to go to Japan in 2023.

> In 2021 I decided to go to Japan in 2023.

If you remove the dates entirely, there's potential for confusion.

> Last year I decided to go to Japan next year.

Hmmm… you mean next year starting from last year or starting from now, so two years from the decision but one year from now, or do you mean you're going this year...???
Avoid that by using at least one date.

> Last year I decided to go to Japan in 2023.